# Double.ToString returns empty for 0

Tags: c#, double

Could anyone help me understand why the "text" variable is empty for the below snippet,

```
double d = 0;

var text = d.ToString("##,###,###,###");
```

If I change the value of d to any non-zero value, I get its correct string representation.

Comment: try with `var text = d.ToString("##,###,###,##0");` if you want not empty strings.

Comment: there is already a format for what you want. `d.ToString("N0")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [The `"#"` Custom Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierD)

> Note that this specifier *never* displays a zero that is not a
>   significant digit, **even if zero is the only digit in the string**. It
>   will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that
>   is being displayed.

If you wanna display it as `00,000,000,000`, you can use [The `"0"` Custom Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Specifier0) instead. But remember, this specifier puts zero if it doesn't match any numeric value in your double.

That means `(15).ToString("00,000,000,000")` will generate `00,000,000,015` as a result.

If you want to display `0` as well other than your other values, just change your last digit format from `#` to `0` like `##,###,###,##0`.

**But** a better way might be using [The numeric `"N"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) in my opinion. This specifiers generates thousands group separator and it's size, decimal separator and it's size (you can omit this part with `N0`) possible negative sign and it's pattern.

```
double d = 0;
var text = d.ToString("N0");
```

Also I want to mentioned about `,` in your string format. You want to group like thousands separator, (and since you don't use *any* [`IFormatProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) in your code) if your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx) is different than `,` character, *that* character will be displayed, not `,`.

For example; I'm in Turkey and my current culture is `tr-TR` and this culture has `.` as a `NumberGroupSeparator`. That's why your code will generate a result in my machine as `##.###.###.###` format not `##,###,###,###`.

Comment: Thanks for this information! That explains it welll.

Answer (score 0):

For string formatting, # represents optional place. For example a format string like "#0" will display first numeric character if the number is equal or greater than 10. Therefore, you need to convert your hashtags to zero if you want to show your number.